# How to export SMS messages from a Nokia 1616 / 1800?

Tags: telephony

I have two old Nokia phones and I'm trying to export all the SMS messages stored in them to my laptop.

The first one is a Nokia-3110c. I managed to connect it to my laptop using a USB cable and exported all messages using the [Nokia PC-suite](http://nokia-pc-suite.com/).

The second is also a Nokia. On the user's manual it says Nokia 1616 / 1800, I am not sure which of the two the phone actually is. So I wanted to use the same method with this phone but apparently this model does not have any USB connector. I tried various search engines but found not relevant information. Do you now if there is a way to get all messages out of this phone as well?

Comment: Are the messages on the phone or on the SIM? If the latter, you could just put it into the other phone to get them out.

Comment: Alas I strongly suspect that it doesn't; it's a phone from 2009 and the Amazon listing boasts of "large SMS storage (up to 250)", which is a large enough guarantee to imply in-phone storage.

Comment: Is there maybe another way to connect the phone to a PC? Infrared, bluetooth? I am pretty ignorant wrt these technologies so I have no idea what may be possible.

Comment: I am not sure I understand why this question has been closed. The phone I am trying to download SMS from is still in use but the model isn't supported any more. If I cannot get messages out of it, it will be disposed of. I would be glad to move this question to another stackexchange forum, but this one seemed the most appropriate to me. I am open for alternative suggestions.